# How to call batch file in deployment environment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to call batch file from java web application using

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("D:/doctemp/convert.bat");
    Process p = pb.start();
```

It works fine when I run application using Netbeans. But when I deploy my application in tomcat batch file does't call.
Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried new ProcessBuilder("CMD.EXE /C D:/doctemp/convert.bat");?

Comment: you need to give relative path of batch.

Comment: it didn't work even from netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are running into some permissions problems.

When deploying on Tomcat, are you including this batch file in your .war file, or must the program use the path provided?

Comment: program must use the path provided.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. by using following code.

```
File dir = new File("D:\\Vers\\doctemp");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c convert.bat", envs, dir);
```

you need to send the full path of cmd.exe to recognize by tomcat. and for font support you need to send environment variables.